# nhibernate and CRLF in an oracle database

Tags: .net, oracle, nhibernate

I've encountered a problem while reading strings I've persisted using nhibernate in an oracle DB.
If I write a string containing a CRLF (0x0D + 0x0A) after I've read it back I get only LF.
The column in the database is a nvarchar2 and the property is mapped in nhibernate as a string (I also tried mapping it as ansistring but there was no difference) like this

```
<property name="ExtraInformation" column="ExtraInformation" type="String" />
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: IMO oracle does not convert the data you are giving to it. How do you verify that the CRLF is converted to LF?

Answer (score 0):

NHibernate dos not perform any kind of string transform (nor should Oracle, unless there's some strange setting I'm not aware of)

The problem is most likely in your own code (i.e. you are not really sending CRLF)

Comment: VS shows the string as "something\r\nsomething" before commiting it to the database, after reading it in another session I get "something\nsomething" back. This is done in a unit test isolated from other code, unless VS reports \r\n incorrectly I think I'm sending CRLF.

Comment: OK, next step is isolating this from NHibernate. Try doing the insert/select with raw ADO.NET.